# How Taking Value of flag from json?

Tags: android, json

I need to take values from web service. Here I used JSON parsing.The output JSON format is given below:

```
{ "result": [{"flag":1} [ { "transactionid": "13" } ] ]}
```

Here I need to take the value of flag and value of transaction id. Using that value I want to start another method. How do I take the value of flag?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(result);
       JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
       JSONObject jsfalg=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       int flag=jsfalg.getInt("flag");
       if(flag==0)
       {
        System.out.println("test6 search");
        final_flag=ecObj.no_data_available_code;
       }else{JSONArray jsonArr1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);String transaction_id[]=new String[jsonArr1.length()];for(int i=0;i<jsonArr1.length();i++)
        {
         JSONObject json_data=jsonArr1.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: don't put too much code in comments section. edit your question and add there...

Comment: i tried that one.but icant be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

The json you posted in not valid. Youcan verify @ http://jsonlint.com/

I assume the json looks like below

```
{ // json object node
    "result": [ // json array result
        {       //  json object node
            "flag": 1
        },
        {
            "transactionid": "13"
        }
    ]
}
```

To parse

```
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("jsonstring");
JSONArray result = jbgetJSONArray("result");
JSONOBject jb1 = (JSONObject)result.getJSONObject(0);
String flag = jb1.getInt("flag");
JSONOBject jb2 = (JSONObject)result.getJSONObject(1);
String id = jb2.getString("transactionid");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json string

First try to run this json here :
http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

See this Example here is nice example...
[Json Parsing](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example)